# Pygame, how to display text on transparent layer?

Tags: python, text, pygame, surface

I'm trying to display text on a separated transparent layer after hitting a bonus. The screen blits for a milisecond and the game continues. Where did i make a mistake?

```py
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
surface = pygame.surface.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def hit():
    screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
    bonus = BONUSFONT.render("+3 points!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    bonus_text = (bonus, (200, 150))
    bonus_end = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000
    if bonus_text and pygame.time.get_ticks() < bonus_end:
        surface.blit(*bonus_text)
```

I checked almost all the questions about surfaces and layers, but nothing helped me

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 variables in global name space:

```py
bonus_text = None
bonus_end = 0
```

`hit` sets `bonus_end` and hast be called once, when the "hit" happens:

```py
def hit():
    global bonus_end, bonus_text  
    bonus = BONUSFONT.render("+3 points!", 1, (0, 0, 0))
    bonus_text = (bonus, (200, 150))
    bonus_end = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 3000
```

Create a function which shows the bonus text_

```py
def show_bonus():
    if bonus_text and pygame.time.get_ticks() < bonus_end:
        surface.blit(*bonus_text)
```

Call the function continuously in the main application loop:

```py
while True:

    # [...]

    # show bonus text
    show_bonus()

    # update display
    # [...]
```

Comment: but when i do this, i get the warning that surface.blit(*bonus_text) "expected an iretable, but got none"

Comment: @marta Then you did something wrong. If you evalute `if bonus_text`, then `bonus_text` cant be `None` in `surface.blit(*bonus_text)`